# Add new language in ResXManager - visual studio

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, resx

I need to add new languages and the language resx files don't exist so far. How can I achieve to duplicate the original resx attributes (build action, custom tool, custom tool namespace) to the new generated resx files. I need to take the attributes from default language file (without language extension).

**Example:**
The default language file:
CalendarModels.resx

- Build Action: Embedded resource
- custom tool: PublicResXFileCodeGenerator
- custom tool namespace: ModelResources

The new one that was created by ResXManager:
CalendarModels.de.resx

- Build Action: Content
- custom tool: Empty
- custom tool namespace: Empty

Is it possible to duplicate the resx attributes?

Thank you for answer.
Br. 
Tomáš

Answer (score 0):

You can open the `.resx` files with a code editor and copy-paste the resources into the new file. Copying the resources and leave them unaltered would be a bit useless. .Net will search for resources for the specified culture first and if it can't find them, look for the fallback in the base `CalendarModels.resx` file.